# parse langtude and latitude to use it again on google map

Tags: android, geolocation

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setText("longtude is :" + location.getLongitude() + "latitude is :" + location.getLatitude());
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check given permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

In onCreate add below lines

```
Location l;
String provider;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);


locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return;
}
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
Criteria c=new Criteria();
provider=locationManager.getBestProvider(c, false);
l=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if(l!=null)
{
 //get latitude and longitude of the location
 double lng=l.getLongitude();
 double lat=l.getLatitude();
 //display on text view
 txt.setText(lng+ ""+ lat);
}
else
{
 txt.setText("No Provider");
}
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0)
{
 double lng=l.getLongitude();
 double lat=l.getLatitude();
 txt.setText(lng+ ""+ lat);
}
```

Comment: thanks , it works for me but longtude and latitude appear on ddms only how display these values  on my activity @pavan kvch